# What is the reason for having numbers within the brackets of a function ?

Tags: command-line, command, function, system-calls

I have seen on many occasions a name of a function (frankly speaking I just call it function because of it typical appearance, they are though sometimes named commands or system calls but I do not know the idea behind labelling them differently),
which contains a number within the brackets part of it, like in exec(1) exec(2) exec(3).

What is the meaning behind putting numbers into them ?

Comment: yes, but I think this is one of the questions that should be redundant as long as they have different key terms in the question, because even if someone has seen some(number) it is not necessary he would associate it with the term "man" or "manual" , but for instance function , system call or something else.

Comment: I agree with Al Hazred here.  The question is, in fact, different, due only to the variant interpretations of `exec(2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` here could be a system call or a bash built-in or something else from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) . And respective man pages related to system call or bash built-in refer to the exec's man page with numbers in the brackets. So if I want to refer to manpage of bash built-in, I would say `exec(1)` and if I want to refer to manpage of system call `exec()` i would say `exec(2)`

The number referrs to particular manpage.
When you see `exec(2)` in a manpage. To know about that particular referred `exec` you should say `man 2 exec`

Answer (score 4):

These numbers disambiguate manual pages that have the same name. They represent the manual section that the page should be retrieved from. As an excerpt from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections) states:

> The manual is generally split into eight numbered sections, organized
>   as follows [...]

Comment: I am still somehow confused, does this mean that exec(1), exec(2),...exec(8) is about the same "function" , but eight different aspects of it ?

Comment: Lets say you want to know about `exec(3)`, you do `man 1 exec` and found out that its a bash built-in command and not a system call `exec()`. Then you do `man 3 exec` which is about a system call. So `exec` here is not necessarily a system call every time. it could be something else (bash built in) with the same name.

Comment: so, the same name is not intended, and some(1) is not related to some(2) or some(8) in their functionality , except the core-meaning of its name. So one some(x) can do something to A and some(y) can do something to B, like theoretically scribble(1) writes something onto the display, scribble(2) writes something onto a critical location like RAM adress, scribble(3) enables some programming language to write something and scribble(7) is a game that teaches how to spell english words ?

Answer (score 2):

The numbers are the sections in the manual. (1), for example, are commands.